# G++: not vectorizing loop with mask

Tags: c++, g++, vectorization

I have a small Loop that I want the compiler to vectorise, I am using the g++ version 7.2.0 and I want the compiler to auto vectorize the following code:

```
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    if(code[i]==2) arr[i]=calc[i];
    else arr[i] = otherCalc[i];
}
```

I tried using a mask like this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    att[i] = (code[i]==2 
        ? calc[i]
        : otherCalc[i]);
}
```

and I used the flags `-O2 -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-optimized` and `-O2 -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-missed`. The reasons for not vectorizing are the following:

`note: not vectorized: control flow in loop.`

`note: bad loop form.`

`note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.`

EDIT: Seems like if I first store the values of the arrays calc and otherCalc in variables it will vectorize, something like this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    int a=calc[i],b=otherCalc[i];
    att[i] = (code[i]==2 
        ? a
        : b);
}
```

Comment: That's the trouble with SIMD: the _single_ instruction. Branching means the calculation instructions can't act on giant blocks of data at once.

Comment: I use another vectorized loop to do all the calculations into those 2 arrays, seems like doing the calculations first and the choice after is an easier solution.

Comment: interesting, but whats the question?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 How to make it vectorise the loop, presumably

Comment: Yest, I want g++ to vectorize the loop, but even with the mask it only works if I create a variable and assign the value to it (like the edit)

Comment: Well, I'll stick my foot in my mouth: your original example _does_ seem to vectorize pretty well under the right conditions. https://godbolt.org/z/2aSeQA . So, what's the different between this case and yours?